# Validating search form on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some problem with the validation. I'm trying to validate params[:search] and params[:miles] that doesn't belong to a database. So far, I've created a tableless model but still need some help figuring out what's wrong with my code. Appreciate your help guys.

user_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @search = Search.new(search: params[:search], miles: params[:miles])


    if params[:search] && params[:miles].present?
    @users = User.near(params[:search], params[:miles], units: :mi)
     elsif params[:search].present?
    @users = User.near(params[:search], 10, units: :mi)
    else
     @users = User.all
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @search, url: users_path, method: :get do |f| %>
    <% if @search.errors.any? %>
      <h2> Errors: </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @search.errors.full_messages do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.label :miles, params[:miles] %>
    <%= f.text_field :miles %>
    <%= f.label :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= f.text_field :search %> </br >
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
  <% end %>
```

search.rb model

```
class Search
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :search
  attr_accessor :miles

  validates_presence_of :search
  validates :miles, inclusion: { in: 0..9 }
end
```

Comment: Where does your code fail? Does the Search errors not showing? Does you get an error of some kind?

Comment: Since you didn't mention your error, its hard to understand whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So user gets to the index page, and fill the search fields: `search` and `miles` 
Then click `Search` and arrive the index controller, where a **new** search is created: `@search = Search.new`.

In no place at your code The Search is 'given' the params the user filled.

Shouldn't you do something like :

`@search = Search.new(search: params[:search], miles: params[:miles])`

or

```
@search = Search.new
@search.search = params[:search]
@search.miles = params[:miles]
```

and then for the validations to start, you need to 'activate' them somehow, like `@search.valid?` which should trigger the validation process

Comment: you're right but i get this error now - wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: Updated my answer, and when you get an error, please specify on which element the error occurred, I assumed it happened at Search.new

Comment: thanks that solved the error problem i need to work on the validation part now

Comment: if you feel your question is answered please mark answer as correct, otherwise please elaborate why your question is still unanswered.

Comment: I'm still working on the validation part so might have questions for you later :)